# Help - Post Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript

**Overview:** 
I got a website that has sentences that people can post to facebook, but in each sentence there are input boxes, which people can change the default value. Kinda like an digital "Mad Lib".

**EXAMPLE** 
I like ***_*_** and I think he is ***_*_**.

- the underscores would be a text-field with a default value that would disappear once someone focuses on it.

Final string: I like JEN and I think she is HOT.

**GOAL** 
Save final String and Post to Facebook (not worried about the facebook yet)

**HTML**

```
<span>I like</span>
<input name="post1_1" value="Tom" type="text" id="post1_1" />
<span>I think she is</span><input name="post1_2" value="Nice" type="text" id="post1_2" />

<a href="javascript:Post1()">POST NOW</a>

<span>My website is</span>
<input name="post2_1" value="Great" type="text" id="post2_1" />

<a href="javascript:Post2()">POST NOW</a>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
var post1_1 = null;
var post1_2 = null;
var post2_1 = null;

function Post1(){
var post1_1 = $('#post1_1').val();
var post1_2 = $('#post1_2').val();
var post1 = 'I like ' + post1_1 + ' I think she is ' + post1_2;
alert(post1);
}

function Post2(){
var post2_1 = $('#post2_1').val();
var post2 = 'My website is ' + post2_1;
alert(post2);
}

</script>
```

I am very new to web any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What seems to be the problem here, officer?

Comment: Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: I updated the script to make more sense. I works! Thanks all. Now I will find out how to post this to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance, there are a few things wrong with your script.

```
post1_1 = ('#post1_1').val();
post2_1 = ('#post2_1').val();
post2_2 = ('#post2_2').val();
```

I'm assuming you're using jQuery here.  You need the `$` in front of the `()`.

```
post1_1 = $('#post1_1').val();
post2_1 = $('#post2_1').val();
post2_2 = $('#post2_2').val();
```

Second, you set these after you set the post variables.

```
var post1 = 'Your are' + post1_1;
var post2 = 'You smell like' + post2_1 + 'and' + post2_2;
```

This will be "Your are null" (which, i'm assuming should be "You are").  You should set the variables to the input values before you use them.

```
var post1_1 = $('#post1_1').val();
var post2_1 = $('#post2_1').val();
var post2_2 = $('#post2_2').val();

var post1 = 'Your are' + post1_1;
var post2 = 'You smell like' + post2_1 + 'and' + post2_2;

alert(post1);
alert(post2);
```

I know this is just an example, but there is no `post2_2` in your HTML, and the sentences in the HTML don't match those in the JavaScript.

Comment: yea, I just wanted to convey that there will be more than just one sentence.

Comment: @GermanMan: Ok, that's what I thought.  Just figured I'd point it out.

Comment: Do you think this data would be easy to post to facebook?

Comment: @GermanMan: I don't know how to use Facebook's API, but I'm sure it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider only the two text fields and an ID of the current sentence. Like `sentence_id[]`, `field1[]`, `field2[]`. You can treat it as array:

```
<form action="javascript:;">

    <div id="sentence-0">
        <input type="hidden" name="sentence_id[0]" value="1" />

        John is at <input type="text" name="field1[0]" /> with <input type="text" name="field2[0]" />

        <button id="submit-sentence-0" class="submit">Send</button>
    </div>


    <div id="sentence-1">
        <input type="hidden" name="sentence_id[1]" value="2" />

        Mary is at <input type="text" name="field1[1]" /> working with <input type="text" name="field2[1]" />

        <button id="submit-sentence-1" class="submit">Send</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Just an idea, hope it helps you.

Comment: Just web standards. Why put inputs on the fly? Sometimes it's useful too. Like Using jQuery .serialize() function upon the form and then passing  all the data through an ajax call. Declaring fields as array, you will have the ability to add as many as you want, and you will not write a line of JS for each field.

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look into it since I don't use Ajax much and I am not familiar with the serialize() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of many ways as to how this could be implemented, but the way this question is worded leaves a lot of ambiguity to what one exactly wants.

Consider the following:

Pre-generated statements such as: I like `X` and I think he is `Y`.

Where `X` and `Y` could be a dropdown or textbox control of choices.

I believe one said something like a textbox, so an html form would be appropriate.

Static example (to be handled by php/django/rails/etc):

```
<form action="/status/" method="post">
  I like <input type="text" name="noun" />
  and I think he is <input type="text" name="verb" />
  <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Now modify this to fit the server side language to handle the request.

Now for a Javascript example (I'm not very good with js):

```
<form name="status" action="handle-data.js">
  I like <input type="text" name="noun" />
  and I think he is <input type="text" name="verb" />
  <a href="javascript: submitform()">Update</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitform(){
    document.status.submit();
  }
</script>
```

In the `handle-data.js` one would likely manipulate the data or whatnot.

See http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

for more Javascript examples.

Comment: I don't think you can submit a form to a JavaScript file.

Comment: I am just using a text-box to get the value. Not trying to submit a form.

Comment: @Rocket I do not know very much about javascript, so sorry about the bad example. And GermanMan-- then would it be a page of verb/noun value pairs? This is the ambiguous part.

Comment: The value could be anything. Its up to the user.